# How to create Yes/NO Alert Dialog in Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog

This is my codes that I commented what I need. I tries some codes but it seems not compatible with Fragment.

```
public class main extends Fragment {

    ImageButton imagebutton;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        imagebutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.im);

        imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Open Yes/No Dialog

                //if Yes do something
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this method:

```
   private void createAndShowAlertDialog() {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
     builder.setTitle("My Title");
     builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
              //TODO
              dialog.dismiss();
         }
     });
     builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
              //TODO
              dialog.dismiss();
         }
     });
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
     dialog.show();
   }
```

Comment: I'm using fragment too. I add the method to my fragment class and call it when I need to confirm when the user wants delete an item.

Comment: No image button in the answer.  Client wants an image button. No 'setPositiveImageButton' that I can find, and the onClick methods work completely differently in fragments than activities, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
    Context mContext;
public MyDialogFragment() {
    mContext = getActivity();
}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Really?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLick-Click!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    return alertDialogBuilder.create();
}
}
```

To create the dialog call:

`new MyDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");`

And to dismiss the dialog from somewhere:
`((MyDialogFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyDialog")).getDialog().dismiss();`

OR

Try using this snippet:

```
AlertDialog.Builder mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyClassNane.this);
mDialog.setTitle("Title");
mDialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete ?");
mDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Click-Click!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

mDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
AlertDialog alert = mDialog.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: I saw this answer before but I don't know how to use it in my codes?

Comment: i have edited my code? does it help? accept the answer is so.

Comment: @MohammadFarahi Try what Sagar posted. "To create the dialog..."

Comment: @MohammadFarahi What's your app say? What does it output on why it's crashing?

Comment: crashes when I add new MyDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog"); in my onClick

Comment: i have added some more code snippet, try using it directly in your activity class

Comment: Where exactly should I put these?

Comment: when do you want to show this dialog? like onLongPress ? OnItemCLick?